# Avoid racism in India towards fellow Indians

Tags: indian-citizens, disputes, north-india

I am a South Indian solo travelling to places in Northern India.

My previous experiences are that I face more racism (due to darker skin tone) in North India (where people have fairer skin tone) than in, say, Eastern Europe.

The places that are in my itinerary are heavily Western-tourist visited.

How do I make sure that I am not treated like a pennyless wanderer (again) and refused services?